# Export Dynamics CRM version to Visio, automatically

Tags: windows, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, visio, dynamics-nav

I would like to say in advance that my knowledge of Dynamics isn't the greatest, but here is my question.

In my company I would like to create a document that has all the information about our servers. What the IP-adress is for instance. Every point of information is static, so it won't change. The only thing that keeps changing ofcourse is the version number/year of CRM / NAV. My question now is, is there a way to automatically update a field in visio or word or something to the correct version number. So in a way that the version/year from CRM get's pushed to that document.

It would be a pain in the bottom to change the version number everytime we update, a couple of times a week. Also, when the document is not up to date, no one will use it.

I hope you can help me with my problem!

Thanks :)

EDIT:
I do have a lot of IT knowledge and I'm a quick learner. So please don't hold back on the difficult solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Are you really updating CRM Server several times a week? Or are you updating your CRM solutions a couple of times a week? The last one sounds a lot more feasible. If you are updating  your CRM server a couple of times I week, I would be very curious why that is.

If it's the last one, you can use the xRM CI framework to get the solution and extract the version number: https://xrmciframework.codeplex.com/

```
$solution = Get-XrmSolution -ConnectionString $connectionString -UniqueSolutionName "Solution unique name"
$solutionInfo.Version
```

The last line gives you the version number. Just note, that the developers must (manually) increase the version number.